# Plotting the graph of a function of a function

Tags: plotting, functions

I am trying to plot the graph of a variable which is a function of the variable against which I wish to plot. For example,
I want to plot `f[r[t]]=2r[t]+3r[t]^2` wrt t and I already have r[t] as an interpolating function obtained as a solution through NDSolve.
If someone can help me, I am ready to provide the actual problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[r,rr, f]
sol = NDSolve[{rr'[t] == rr[t] Cos[t + rr[t]], rr[0] == 1}, rr, {t, 0, 20}];

r[t_?NumericQ] := rr[t] /. sol[[1]]
f[u_] := 2 u + 3 u^2

Plot[{r[t], f[r[t]]}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotLegends -> {"r[t]", "f[r[t]]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: A very useful Code for numeric functional analysis, a nested function of functions.

Comment: I tried to integrate `f[r[t]]` above using `NIntegrate[...]`, but it does not work because (I think) `NIntegrate[]` accepts a function not the values of the function. If so, how can I integrate the function implied by the list of numbers obtained from `f[r[t]]`?

Comment: @TugrulTemel, with the updated version, `NIntegrate[]` should work.